# pull previous value and current value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement the input/output for a table is shown Below.
For same `Column1` value I have different `Column3` value. `Column2` is unique for a specific set of values in `Column1` and `Column2`. I need to derive the output so that 
for every `Column1` value its should pull "last" and "last but one" record.

Input

---

```
Column1 Column2     Column3
ABC     1           Hary
ABC     2           Mark
ABC     3           David

BCD     1           Marc
BCD     2           Shaw
BCD     3           Hary
BCD     4           Hary

XYZ     1           Lousie
XYZ     2           Shelly
XYZ     3           Marie
XYZ     4           Hary
```

Output

---

```
Column1     Previous    Latest
ABC         Mark        David
BCD         Hary        Hary
XYZ         Marie       Hary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to produce the desired output:

```
select column1
     , max(prev)   keep (dense_rank last order by column2) as previous
     , max(latest) keep (dense_rank last order by column2) as latest
  from (select column1
             , column2
             , column3 as latest
             , lag(column3) over(partition by column1
                                     order by column2) as prev
          from table_name
        )
group by column1
```

Result:

```
COLUMN1 PREVIOUS LATEST
------- -------- ------
ABC     Mark     David  
BCD     Hary     Hary   
XYZ     Marie    Hary
```

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/95e3d/1)